# installing SSIS feature in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-express

Does SQL Server 2008 Express support Integration Services? When I try to create an Integration Services project, it says that I have to install Integration Services, but I cannot find the option in the setup for the installation. How can I install it?

Is there any service pack for this?

Comment: no, express editions do not support this. Express editions are stripped down limited editions of SQL Server.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas: actually, you're wrong. See my response. SQL Server Express **with Advanced Services** has the Integration Services included.

Comment: thanks. it has been a while....

Answer (score 1):

The [SQL Server 2008 Express **with Advanced Services**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365248%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) version does have SSIS in the box. If you've not installed that exact version, then you'll need to get the right version to have SSIS.

In order to develop SSIS packages, you need to have features enabled in Visual Studio. For Visual Studio 2010 and higher, those features are packaged in the [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx) that can be downloaded and installed .